# Paperclip 4, Amazon S3 & rspec: how to stub file upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm writing tests with rspec and am a bit struggling with Paperclip 4. At the moment I'm using webmock to stub requests but image processing is slowing tests down.

Everything I read suggest to use stubs like so:

```
Profile.any_instance.stub(:save_attached_files).and_return(true)
```

It doesn't work since :save_attached_files disappeared with Paperclip 4 as far as I can tell.

What's the proper way to do it now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Add this to your `rails_helper.rb` in your config block:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Stub saving of files to S3
  config.before(:each) do
    allow_any_instance_of(Paperclip::Attachment).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting. From my understanding though, this is the analog of the old stub way and I assumed the proper way to do it. Will try the alternatives out!

Comment: yeah I was a little disappointed, it looked like an interesting/clean solution :)

Comment: This made my tests faster, not slower. Using this stub and the Paperclip class overrides in @Nycen's answer **really** increased the speed of my tests that involved Paperclip attachments. Cheers.

Comment: This made my tests faster too.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't exactly answer my question, but I found a way to run faster specs thanks to [this dev blog](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/11/paperclip-and-rspec-stubbing-paperclip-imagemagick-to-make-specs-run-faster-but-with-image-resolution-validation/comment-page-1/#comment-2202), so I'm posting it if it can help someone else.

Just add this piece of code at the beginning of your spec file or in a helper. My tests are running 3x faster now.

```
# We stub some Paperclip methods - so it won't call shell slow commands
# This allows us to speedup paperclip tests 3-5x times.
module Paperclip
  def self.run cmd, params = "", expected_outcodes = 0
    cmd == 'convert' ? nil : super
  end
end
class Paperclip::Attachment
  def post_process
  end
end
```

#### Paperclip > 3.5.2

For newer versions of Paperclip, use the following:

```
module Paperclip
  def self.run cmd, arguments = "", interpolation_values = {}, local_options = {}
    cmd == 'convert' ? nil : super
  end
end

class Paperclip::Attachment
  def post_process
  end
end
```

Comment: Since you've said this answer doesn't answer your question, shouldn't @madcow's answer be the accepted answer since it does address your question?

Comment: Awesome, got a downvote 3 years later because I didn't accept an answer that was posted 1.5 years after I answered my own question. I would've been better not answering at all. Good lesson here.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, and it doesn't seem like the downvoter provided a reason why they did. You may be jumping to conclusions.

Comment: I jumped to that conclusion too ;) It doesn't mean I'm also right about the downvote though. Anyway, that was a stupid comment in a moment of weakness.

Answer (score 1):

I had a heckuva time dealing with this. I didn't want to test Paperclip per se -- rather, I needed a file to exist on my model so I can test a very sensitive custom class.

None of the other answers worked for me (Rails 5, Rspec 3.5) so I gave up on stubbing AWS or using the Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers. Nothing worked and it ate up an entire day! Finally I gave up on Paperclip altogether and went this route:

```
list = build(:list)
allow(list).to receive_message_chain("file.url") { "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/guess_fullname.csv" }
importer = Importer.new(list)
expect(importer.set_key_mapping).to eq({nil=>:email_address, :company=>:company, :fullname=>:full_name})
```

Where my `models/list.rb` has `has_attached_file :file` and Importer is a class I wrote that takes the file, which was already uploaded to S3 by paperclip before the class is initialized, and processes it. The `file.url` would otherwise be the S3 URL, so I give it the path in my repo to a testing csv file. `set_key_mapping` is a method in my class that I can use to verify the processing part worked.

Hope this saves somebody a few hours...

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `AWS.stub!` in your `spec/spec_helper.rb`? Give that a try.